# R count weights ~ similar but dif question

Tags: r, weighted, psych

```
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame("person"=c(1:100),
                  "group"=c(sample(1:2,100,r=T)),
                  "type"=c(sample(1:3,100,r=T)),
                  "value"=c(sample(20:40,100,r=T)),
                  "weight"=c(sample(100:300,100,r=T)),
                  "score" = c(sample(1:3,100,r=T)))
```

What I aim to do is first aggregate by "value" and then apply the "weight" to the score. Desired output is like the following----

```
want = data.frame("value"=sort(rep(unique(data$value),6)),
                  "group"=rep(1:2,63),
                  "type"=rep(1:3,42),
                  "score"=sample(1:3,126,r=T))
```

However I aim to have the "want" data frame include the WEIGHTED score variable.

--

Another example inspired from @Maurits Evers thank you. I think this is what I aim for.

```
data = data.frame("person"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  "group"=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2),
                  "type"=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1),
                  "value"=c(5,6,5,5,8,9,12,12,7,6),
                  "score"=c(3,3,2,3,3,2,1,1,1,1),
                  "weight"=c(100,200,100,200,150,300,100,200,200,300))
data$scoreWEIGHT = data$score * data$weight
aggregate(data$scoreWEIGHT, by=list(Category=data$value), FUN=sum)
#but i aim to use the count function ()
```

Comment: There is no logic as to obtain what you want. what do you mean by aggregate by value then apply the weight to the score? No one can read your mind. You need to be elaborate

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. It's not clear how to "aggregate" data to reproduce your expected output. For example, your input `data` contains 100 rows, while your expected `want` has 126 rows. That doesn't look like something that would be the result of an `aggregate`/`summarise` function. Can you give a more explicit example, preferably using *smaller* (i.e. less than 100 rows) sample data and matching expected output?

Comment: Yes I do apologize as I am not a native speaker of english. In the data file, there are multiple persons with the same value.  By aggregate on value what I mean is that I want one row per value--and per group and type. So the 126 comes from the unique number of values * 2 groups * 3 types--does this make sense? In other words, I want to estimate how many persons there are with value # in group # and type #

Comment: @bvowe Sorry, I'm still unclear. I don't understand what you mean by *"the unique number of values * 2 groups * 3 types"* in connection with wanting to calculate *"the WEIGHTED score variable"*. It would really help if you were to provide a *smaller* representative example. For example, give an example with 10 or less rows and corresponding expected output, and then explicitly walk us through the expected output for one of the `value`s.

Comment: for every combination of a unique value (since some repeat), group, and type, I want to get a weighted count. does that make sense?